# How to extract a value from a csv string and insert it into a column in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have the following table in SQL Server:

```
Value  String (csv)                  Name Color 
------------------------------------------------------------------- 
1      Simi,123456,abc@123,Blue,45   Simi  Dog
```

I want to extract 'Blue' from the csv string and update the value in the color column.

```
Value  String                       Name  Color 
-------------------------------------------------------------------  
1      Simi,123456,abc@123,Blue,45  Simi  Blue
```

Comment: Based on what? How do you know what part of the string to extract? Also, please read [ask] and edit your question to proper formatting. I've tried to but all the `&nbsp;` gave me a head spin.

Comment: @ZoharPeled I gave an answer below which assumes he wants to extract the second-to-last CSV value, which is a color, and update with that.  But I'm prepared to be wrong.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Sorry for the head spin I am new to SO. I did mention the color.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I think assuming the OP intent most of the time leads to giving the wrong answer, I guess your assumption was correct this time :-)

Comment: @ZoharPeled I guess this is my lucky day then :-)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thanks buddy that is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET Color = SELECT REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(String),
                                     CHARINDEX(',', REVERSE(String)) + 1,
                                     CHARINDEX(',', REVERSE(String), CHARINDEX(',', REVERSE(String)) + 1) - CHARINDEX(',', REVERSE(String)) - 1))
```